# MySQL Select Same Columns Twice

Tags: mysql

I have a table populated as

```
userID INT
firstName VARCHAR(255)
lastName VARCHAR(255)
refID INT
```

Where `refID` is the `userID`, this particular user was referred by.

I want to create a report that can pull the referrer and referee in one query, which I'm having trouble figuring out.

The final report would look like

```
referrer first name,referrer last name,referee first name,referee last name
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for SELF JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your above table links to a `users` table, or similar, so you'd want:

```
SELECT referrer.firstname, referrer.lastname, referee.firstname, referee.lastname
from yourtable
left join users AS referrer ON yourtable.userID = referrer.id
left join users AS referree ON yourtable.refID = referee.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select rr.firstName, rr.lastname, re.firstname, re.lastname
from mytable rr left join mytable re
on rr.userId = re.refId
```